# "Due to lack of / For lack of"?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Which of these statements is grammatically sound? :

- I would like to point out that I have already graduated and have marked 5th year in the question regarding the current status of my education **due to lack of** a better option.
- I would like to point out that I have already graduated and have marked 5th year in the question regarding the current status of my education **for lack of** a better option.

Comment: Hi Vineet Kaushik. We're not really here for checking sentences as such; we like to be able to answer questions with a broader application. If you could find a way to make your question applicable to more people, e.g. by specifying what you're unsure about, that would be great. Please use *edit* under the tags to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical and equivalent. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for) includes the following definition of *for*:

> *literary* 
>   Because; since:
>   *he felt guilty, for he knew that he bore a share of responsibility for Fanny’s death*

Since this tends to be a literary use, *due to* or *because of* would be more apppriate in most common contexts.